# How to compare pandas dataframes ignoring column order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have two pandas dataframes:

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame({ 0: ['a', 'b', 'c'], 1: [9, 8, 7], 2: [True, True, False] })
df_b = pd.DataFrame({ 0: [9, 8, 7], 1: [True, True, False], 2: ['a', 'b', 'c'] })
```

These two should be equal if ignoring column order, because they each contain the same 3 columns with the same row order. Every solution I've seen for this sort of thing tries to match based on column names, but that doesn't matter for me.

Answer (score 1):

In your case do

```
df_a.apply(set,1).eq(df_b.apply(set,1))
Out[32]: 
0    True
1    True
2    True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: I think you cannot compare row by row - consider `df_a` has first row `a  9   True`, `df_b` has first row `9  a   True` . Then dataframes aren't equal (if I understand it correctly). I think one needs to compare by columns.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly the question boils down to whether the dataframes have the same columns or not, regardless of the order of columns, and we are checking the equality of dataframes, not individual values.
So the solution would be :

```
def check_if_frames_are_equal(df_a, df_b) -> bool :
    """
    Checks if two dataframes are equal (have the same columns),
    regardless of the order of the columns.

    Parameters
    ----------
    df_a : pandas.DataFrame.
        First dataframe.
    df_b : pandas.DataFrame.
        Second dataframe.

    Returns
    -------
    bool.
        True if the dataframes are equal, False otherwise.

    Example
    -------
    df_a = pd.DataFrame({ 0: ['a', 'b', 'c'], 1: [9, 8, 7], 2: [True, True, 
    False] })
    df_b = pd.DataFrame({ 0: [9, 8, 7], 1: [True, True, False], 2: ['a', 
    'b', 'c'] })
    df_c = pd.DataFrame({ 0: [9, 8, 7], 1: [True, True, False], 2: ['a', 
    'd', 'c'] })

    check_if_frames_are_equal(df_a, df_b)
        >>> True

    check_if_frames_are_equal(df_a, df_c)
        >>> False

    """

    return {tuple(df_a[c]) for c in df_a.columns} == {tuple(df_b[c]) for c 
in df_b.columns}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, based on `numpy`:

```
(df_b.T.values == df_a.T.values[:,None]).all(axis=2).any(axis=1).all()
```